# warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Right now I am working on rails 2.3.3 If I run my project in terminal, I get this warning.

> /home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, Try to add below code into `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file.

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf
```

It looks like newer versions of rails already [registers](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d73269ba53992d8a01e5721aad3d23bc2b11dc4f) it.

OR

Try using [lookup_by_extenstion](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Mime/Type/lookup_by_extension/class) before defining it.

In same `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf unless Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:pdf)
```